Imported igraph graph does not correctly recognize nodes
I'm switching from networkx to igraph for my graph analysis project and the graph i'm loading from a file is incorrectly classified as completely disconnected.
Here is the code i'm using:
from sys import argv,getsizeof
from igraph import Graph

# read network file
assert len(argv)>=2, "Must specify a file containing a graph"
G = Graph.Load(argv[1],format="edgelist")
graphsize = sum(getsizeof(v) for v in G.vs) + sum(getsizeof(e) for e in G.es)
graphsize = graphsize // (1024*1024)
print(f"Graph occupies {graphsize} MBs in memory")

print(G.ecount()) # shows the correct number of edges in the graph

print("Graph is connected" if Graph.is_connected(G) else "Graph is not connected")

comps = G.connected_components()
print(max(comps.sizes()))

The max(comps.sizes()) line prints a 1, meaning that each node is counted as being in its own separate component.
The same analysis with networkx on the same file correctly said the graph was connected. How do i fix this?

Is your file in the appropriate format for the edgelist reader (zero-based contiguous integer indices)? See the docs for the requirements. You probably want the NCOL reader instead, which supports arbitrary vertex names, and does not interpret the numbers in the file as indices.
